# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space, How can i free memory?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Here is the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.media.sound.JavaSoundAudioClip.readStream(JavaSoundAudioClip.java:328)
at com.sun.media.sound.JavaSoundAudioClip.loadAudioData(JavaSoundAudioClip.java:307)
at com.sun.media.sound.JavaSoundAudioClip.<init>(JavaSoundAudioClip.java:93)
at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.createAppletAudioClip(AppletAudioClip.java:108)
at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.<init>(AppletAudioClip.java:49)
at java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(Applet.java:279)
at tetris.TetrisAudioPlayer.<init>(TetrisAudioPlayer.java:31)
at tetris.GamePanel.<init>(GamePanel.java:181)
at tetris.TetrisPanelsController.actionPerformed(TetrisPanelsController.java:155)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:272)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6375)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6140)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4737)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4565)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:684)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:643)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:641)
```

Description of the problem: in the same frame I switch between JPanels, one of them has an Audioclip, if I switch back and forth between this JPanel and another I get this error. I want to free the memory from the JPanel with the Audioclip when I quit it, but seems that assigning null to it doesn't work, any idea?
PS The AudioClip class extends JApplet, maybe it is the cause of the problem?

As requested here is the portion of code that "leaks":
This is the AudioClip

```
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;


public class TetrisAudioPlayer extends JApplet {

private AudioClip song; // Sound player

private URL songPath; // Sound path

private boolean playing;

public TetrisAudioPlayer(String filename) {

    try {

        //songPath = new URL(getCodeBase(),filename); // Get the Sound URL

        songPath= this.getClass().getResource(filename);

        song = Applet.newAudioClip(songPath); // Load the Sound
    }

    catch(Exception e){} // Satisfy the catch

}

public void playSound() {
    song.loop(); // Play
    playing=true;
}

public void stopSound() {
    song.stop(); // Stop
    playing=false;
}

public void playSoundOnce() {
    song.play(); // Play only once
    playing=true;
}

public boolean playing(){
    return playing;
}
}
```

And this is how I change the JPanels, gamePanel is the JPanel wich contains the AudioClip, the error occur only with the AudioClip, without it there is no problem with this code.

```
        tetrisFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
        tetrisFrame.getContentPane().invalidate();

        gamePanel=null;

        mainMenuPanel= new MainMenuPanel(this);
        tetrisFrame.getContentPane().add(mainMenuPanel);
        tetrisFrame.getContentPane().validate();
        tetrisFrame.getContentPane().repaint();
```

Comment: There's no way for us to identify any issues if no code is reproduced. Please copy the relevant portions of the code here.

Comment: Better yet, specify JRE version and paste the command-line arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried by setting the JVM arguments with
1. `-Xms` as the initial size of the heap
2. `-Xmx` which sets the maximum size of the heap

Increase the heap value based on your RAM

**Example:**

```
-Xms512m 
-Xmx1024m

Java -Xmx1024m ......
```

Comment: This question is not about eclipse

Comment: @richarbernal: But these might be simple issues, which developer can encounter.

Comment: But changing eclipse memory will have no influence on the JVM inside which the code runs.

Comment: A simple edit would make this answer more applicable to the posed question. On the other hand, simply increasing the heap size will not fix the underlying issue, it will just postpone the eventual crash.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: While running through command line, if developer sets max heap size `-Xmx1024m` and runs it. There is a chance to execute, If feel.

Comment: Developer must set these as JVM arguments of his program and not in `eclipse.ini`, as you stated. Fix the answer. BTW in case you're wondering, the downvote is not my doing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I have updated my answer. Regarding downvote, its OK. May be SO user felt my answer might be incorrect at that moment. But thanks for the suggestions

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but I agree with MarkoTopoInik, increasing the heap size will not resolve the problem, I want to go back and forth the two JPanels as many times as I want without leaking memory. I'm wondering if it's an issue linked to Applet (since the leak comes from the AudioClip).

Answer (score 2):

You might have to assign more memory. 
Assigning an object to null just marks it to be cleared by the gc.

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841723/exception-in-thread-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-spa)

Answer (score 0):

Call below method in onDestroy() or onPause()

```
Runtime.getRuntime().runFinalization();
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
System.gc();
```

But java internally call System.gc() method this is not correct way to free memory , but using above code memory was clear

Answer (score -1):

How to free memory in java:

```
public void freememory(){
    Runtime basurero = Runtime.getRuntime(); 
    basurero.gc();
}
```

Call this twice to get better results.

Comment: Calling `System.gc()` and variations only SUGGEST the garbage collector to run. There's no guarantee.